is $x^4-x+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$
i was wondering if i checked correctly. i found all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ of degree 2 which are irreducible and checked if they are divisible without remainder
the polynomials i tried were
$$
x^2+1\\
x^2+x+2\\
x^2+2x+2
$$
however i found that none of these polynomials were divisible without remainder, suggesting that the polynomial is irreducible.

What if it's linear times cubic?

While I share Gerry's concern, I also want to commend you for not just verifying the absence of zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_3$. We have had too many askers doing just that :-)

In order to check if a polynomial of degree $4$ is irreducible you need to check first if it can be divided by polynomials of degree $1$ like $x+1$. 
if you evaluate your polynomial at $x=-1$ you get: $(-1)^4-(-1)+1=1+1+1\equiv0\,(mod\,3)$. which implies that $$x^4-x+1=(x+1)(x^3-x^2+x+1)$$
and this degree $3$ polynomial is irreducible since it has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.
